# Powerbi error- A web API key can only be specified when a web API key name is provided

Tags: api, powerbi

I am trying to get powerBi to pull data from:
https://api.wifisensorcloud.com/

I have been going over all the api documentation and reviewing powerbi support forums and I cannot get powerbi to pull the JSON

The supplier have given me the API Key, but I get the following error: “A web API key can only be specified when a web API key name is provided”
[image]

BELOW ARE THE INFORMATION FROM SUPPLIER

Connecting to the API The 5 services are hosted at:

https://api.wifisensorcloud.com/Users.svc

https://api.wifisensorcloud.com/Locations.svc

https://api.wifisensorcloud.com/Devices.svc

https://api.wifisensorcloud.com/Sessions.svc

https://api.wifisensorcloud.com/Lookups.svc

Connections using any protocol other than https (such as http) will be rejected. Requests for data should use the GET method with parameters supplied in a query string whereas data submissions/updates should use the POST method with parameters supplied in a JSON object. Examples of each of these methods are on the next pages.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to that jquery call, you need to set the API Key Name to "APIToken" in the options for [Web.Contents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/web-contents).

The other parts of the `data:` argument can go on the URI as part of the query string.

The reason for this is that the API Key is a secret, and Power Query handles it differently from the rest of the parts of the HTTP call.

Comment: Hi David, thank you for you reply. so under the PowerBI->get data-> web. I need to key in what website? thank you.

Comment: Everything in `url` and `data` from jquery except the APIToken.  That is specified per example 3 here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/web-contents#example-3

Comment: Thanks, I manage to connect to the web with API key. But the data I pull is not actual data I need. I unable to Requests for data should use the GET method with parameters.