# API key format using PowerBI Get data via Web

Tags: powerbi

I am just learning API and this seems like it should be very simple, so thank you for your help.

I am using PowerBI get Data via Web. I get the warning:

> "A webAPI key can only be specified when a web API key name is provided."

[image: PowerBIScreenshot]

I do see that this similar question has been answered,

[Powerbi error- A web API key can only be specified when a web API key name is provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73523595/powerbi-error-a-web-api-key-can-only-be-specified-when-a-web-api-key-name-is-pr)
yet

1. The script is not accepted for me to see to edit the script via Transform Data
2. I do not understand where JSON come fits.

I have tried using
api_key = "XXXX..." and
api_key = XXXX...
neither worked. My `api_key` does work when I use it in a web browser.